# FontStyles other than standard

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

How can I set the FontStyle to Condensed Bold ? or Condensed Bold Italic?
FontStyle properties does not have other than standard values.

My exact font is: Myriad Pro
Font Style: Bold Condensed

How can I create a font based on this truetype?

Note: The font is .OTF OpenType

Comment: are you using Winforms or WPF

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Font Styles with C# Graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649264/custom-font-styles-with-c-sharp-graphics)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* something like this should do it.

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Condensed Bold");
Font font = new Font(
   fontFamily,
   16,
   FontStyle.Regular,
   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

To list available font familys (from link in comments)

```
private void PopulateListBoxWithFonts()
{
    listBox1.Width = 200;
    listBox1.Location = new Point(40, 120);
    foreach ( FontFamily oneFontFamily in FontFamily.Families )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(oneFontFamily.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work.
My exact font is Myriad Pro
Font Style: Bold Condensed

If I try to enter in the font family "Myriad Pro Bold Condensed" I get an error that the fond cannot be found

Comment: Have you checked here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.aspx Added example to list available font familys.

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise `or` to combine FontStyles

```
FontStyle ItalicBoldUnderline = FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline;
```

Comment: But the standard styles don't contain "Bold Condensed"

Answer (score 0):

From a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649685/1218809):

Can you not just use the font name as it appears in the control panel? Most fonts that aren't regular, bold or italic actually have a subfamily type of "regular" anyways. If you download the font properties extensions from Microsoft you can see this on the Names tab. The way the the control panels lists them and the way that .Net knows about them is sometimes different so its a good idea to list out all of the fonts from .Net's perspective:

```
var installed_fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
    var families = installed_fonts.Families;
    var allFonts = new List<string>();
    foreach(FontFamily ff in families){
        allFonts.Add(ff.Name);
    }
    allFonts.Sort();
    foreach(String s in allFonts){
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

And here's a sample that use Franklin Gothic Demi Cond (which is listed in the CP as "Franklin Gothic Cond Demi")

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Test", new Font("Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", 12), new Solid
```

Comment: I know you sort of gave credit to the other person by linking to their answer, but copying and pasting someone else's answer verbatim is 1) plagarism and 2) useless. If the *exact same answer* applies to a different question, then that question is undoubtedly a duplicate of the other question and should be flagged as such instead.

Comment: @CodyGray : "then that question is undoubtedly a duplicate of the other question and should be flagged as such instead"
How do I flag it as a duplicate? Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: I already voted to close this one as a duplicate. In the future, look for the little "flag" link underneath the question's tags. I'm 99% sure that you can flag a question as a duplicate of another one. That flag goes into the moderator queue where more experienced users can judge whether or not they agree with your assessment. I forget exactly how it works, because those of us that have been around for a long time slowly acquire moderator privileges ourselves. Related reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-as-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @CodyGray: Ya, I see the "flag" link. I am new to this Space. Thanks for the advice :)